# Read content (XML) from Android WebView

Tags: android, xml, webview

when i try to get the html source code from webview i use this example for my solution:

[Extracting HTML from a WebView](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/)

now i want to parse a page which has no html content. the page displays only a text extracted from  xml source.

does anybody have an idea how to get the content (or xml source code) from webview?

best regards

EXAMPLE: XML

```
< ID >test< /ID > <BR>

< Status >0< /Status >
```

Is shown as: test0 in webview

I want get the "test0" and put it to string

Comment: Aha, so you receive XML data and would like to get everything between tags into a single string? No delims?

Comment: the delims arent shown in webview. i don't know why... i want the content whether or not with delims

Comment: Does it have to be from `WebView` or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: It should be a webview because i develop a small framework that expand webview

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: Use the same approach as is shown in the linked-to blog post. Devise some JavaScript that grabs the data out of your Web page and call that JavaScript via `loadUrl()`, routing the results to some JavaScript interface you injected into the `WebView` via `addJavascriptInterface()`.

Option #2: Don't use `WebView` at all, and use `HttpURLConnection` or `HttpClient` to fetch the XML source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to take option #1 but i dont know how to write this javascript. -> javascript novice :-/

Comment: how can i grab the data from webview?